# Excel datetime format to R for date and time of day

Tags: r, excel, datetime

I have a data frame `df` that has a column `datetime` with datetimes from Excel of the format e.g. `41653.34` corresponding to `1/14/2014 8:12:00`.

I can convert it to YYYY-MM-DD using:

`df$datetime <- as.Date(df$datetime, origin = "1899-12-30")`

However, this loses the information about the time of day of the raw data. How can I convert this data to a date and time instead of just a date?

Thank you.

Comment: `as.POSIXct(as.Date(df$datetime, origin = "1899-12-30"))`

Comment: @Matt Perfect, thank you!

Comment: It pays to be careful with this.  Check the examples in the help for `as.Date`.  The origin for Windows excel is 1899-12-30 but for Mac excel its 1904-01-01. There is also a problem with excel treating 1900 as a leap year (it wasn't).